# Перемещать картинку пока палец находится на экране смартфона

Tags: android, разработка-игр

Столкнуля с проблемой.

Есть картника. Её нужно перемещать пока на экране стоит палец.
Цикл не помогает...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите код, с чем именно проблема возникла.

Comment: добавил картнику с кодом

Comment: а где ссылка на объект картинки, которую нужно перемещать? У картинки есть координаты, как и у нажатия, нужно присвоить координаты нажатия картинке.

Comment: я все это знаю... уже даже делал.

Comment: но суть в том что допустим есть конпка движения в право, палец тронеться её, но действие сработает лишь один раз, а надо что бы было пока не отпустит.

Comment: тач ивенты есть разные, в том числе и на движение пальца, а не только на соприкосновение